# How to Insert mailto link inside php array?

Tags: php, html

I want to insert a mailto link to my php footer. How should i go about to create that? This is my code so far.

```
 <?php $names = array("&copyDusan Biga", "&copyStian Stord", "&copyAsle Foss");
   $arrlength = count($names);

   for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
   echo $names[$x];
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

It is basic footer content. So i want it to have a mailto link right next to the names. So *"&copyDusan Biga (mailto link here)"*. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you're leaving out the semicolons on those HTML entities on purpose?

Comment: Did you run into a string quoting syntax issue when adding your mail links? Why not just use plain HTML instead of a PHP loop? It's only 3 names anyway.

Comment: You're putting their email on the webpage in pain text? I hope they enjoy spam.

Comment: @mario No it works just fine. It's just part of a task i have to do, so PHP is required.

Comment: @JohnConde It's just for practice. The site is not going to be used by anyone besides me.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy Not quite sure what you mean

Comment: @DusanBiga: `&copy` is missing the trailing semicolon needed to display the copyright symbol. Most browsers will probably make some effort to avoid interpreting the entire rest of the document as a single monumental entity, but I'm not sure the behavior is well-defined.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ahhh i see. I just made it as a part of the whole name and  they came out fine in chrome. They don't need to be there i just forgot to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a very professional approach but, as you say, if it's for practice, it's all right, we all have to learn.

One of the 10000000000000 options is:

```
<?php 
$names = array("&copyDusan Biga", "&copyStian Stord", "&copyAsle Foss");
$emails = array("biga@mail.yes", "stian@mail.yes", "foss@mail.yes");
$arrlength = count($names);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
   echo $names[$x]. " - <a href='mailto:".$emails[$x]."'>".$emails[$x]."</a>";
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

A better one would be:

```
<?php
$names = array(
"&copyDusan Biga"=>"biga@mail.yes", 
"&copyStian Stord"=>"stian@mail.yes", 
"&copyAsle Foss"=>"foss@mail.yes");

foreach($names as $name=>$email) {
     echo $name. " - <a href='mailto:".$email."'>".$email."</a>";
     echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: That looks good enough for me! I am just trying get wrap my head around php and how it works. It is as you say, a lot of possible ways to do it so it's hard for me to figure out what to do and how to do it on my own. I watched a friend of mine do this as an array inside a array. Was super hard to understand. But this was way better. Thanks for the help!